# Viewcontroller class method is not calling

Tags: ios, objective-c

hello i want to play through watchKit .i have set all things.but when i am awake parent application from watchKit on button press it awake but from playerController class i have a method  to play poem. but this method is not called my code in appdelegate is below.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply {


NSString *str=[userInfo objectForKey:@"counterValue"];
//reply(@{@"one":@"string"});

PlayerController *vc=[[PlayerController alloc] init];

if ([vc isKindOfClass:[PlayerController class]]){
    if ([str isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        [vc playpoems];
        NSString *theee=@"12345";
        reply(@{@"one":theee});
    }

}
}
```

in this code i got Log from reply block but only method from class is not calling...this method is properly working in class.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a new instance of viewcontroller in appdelegate.
please try with this code as i am telling.

in your .m file

```
@implementation PlayerController

PlayerController *selfvc;

+(PlayerController *)getInstance{
    return selfvc;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    selfvc =self;
}
```

and in your header file

```
@interface PlayerController : UIViewController


+(PlayerController *)getInstance;

@end
```

and then in your appdelegate try with this code

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply {


NSString *str=[userInfo objectForKey:@"counterValue"];
//reply(@{@"one":@"string"});

PlayerController *vc=[PlayerController getInstance];


if ([vc isKindOfClass:[PlayerController class]]){
    if ([str isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        [vc playpoems];
        NSString *theee=@"12345";
        reply(@{@"one":theee});
    }

}
}
```

and then your controller function will be called.

Comment: not working...also i got reply in Log in my code that also not getting by this.

Comment: Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=2 "The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply()